# Reply to an SMS and send it to someone else

Tags: sms

Sometimes when I reply to an SMS, I also want to send that same SMS to another person. On my previous non-android phones this was easy, every SMS was a single message, as opposed to the threads in Android. I could just add another receiver there.

When I answer an SMS in Android, I do not have the option to add another receiver. Is there any workaround?

(Android 2.3 on a Samsung Galaxy Gio)

Answer (score 5):

You could long-tap the message, select "Copy message text", then paste that into the input field of a thread with the new recipient.

Answer (score 0):

**Works in 2.3.6**

*I have 2.3.6 version (galaxy y). I am not sure if this works in 2.3 alone but this answer could help others as this (text forwarding) is tricky in android which you won't find any menu options directly.*

Even I had trouble forwarding initially but I found the actual answer from Hedgeterimmer's answer.

Long tap the message text (message options menu appears)
Scroll down the menu and look for forward option (button) and that's what you wanted